# Prove that the closure of a bounded borel set is contained in a bounded in open set

Tags: general-topology

### Problem Statement

Given a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, consider a bounded set $E$. Here we take bounded to mean that a set is contained in a compact set. The closure $\bar{E}$ is clearly compact, as it is a closed set contained in a compact set. **I would like to prove that there exists a bounded open set $U$ such that $\bar{E} \subseteq U$.**

The motivation for this question comes from [William Arveson's notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Earveson/Dvi/rieszMarkov.pdf) on Radon measures. In particular, the author uses this fact in the proof of Proposition 1.1 and says a simple covering argument suffices to prove it.

### Thoughts

I am assuming I need to start with an open cover of $\bar{E}$ and use compactness to reduce this to a finite subcover. The union of the subcover is open but I don't know if it is necessarily bounded. I guess I could also try starting with a compact set $F$ such that $E \subseteq F$. Then any finite subcover of $F$ is a subcover of $\bar{E}$ but then I run into the same issue regarding boundedness.

### Relying on local compactness

I think I have a proof that relies on the local compactness of $X$. For each $x \in \bar{E}$ let $C_{x}$ be an associated compact neighbourhood which must exist by local compactness of $X$. Since $C_{x}$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ it contains an open set $U_{x}$ containing $x$. The sets $U_{x}$ form an open cover of $\bar{E}$. Since $\bar{E}$ is compact, there exists a finite subcover such that
$$
\bar{E} \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}U_{x_{k}} \subseteq \bigcup^{n}_{k=1}C_{x_k}
$$

Let $A = \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}U_{x_{k}}$ and $B = \bigcup^{n}_{k=1}C_{x_k}$. $A$ is clearly an open set which contains $\bar{E}$. Since $B$ is a finite union of compact sets, it is also compact and thus $A$ is bounded.

This proof heavily relies on local compactness of the space $X$. **If we remove this assumption, does the claim cease to hold?**

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro updated, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. The following are equivalent:

1. evey $x\in X$ has a compact neighbourhood
2. every subset $S$ of a compact set is contained in an open set that has compact closure.
3. every Borel subset $S$ of a compact set is contained in an open set that has compact closure.

$[(1)\Rightarrow (2)]$ $\overline S$ is compact, so by (1) it can be covered by finitely many open sets $U_1,\cdots, U_m$ such that $\overline U_i$ is compact. By the identity $\overline{A\cup B}=\overline A\cup \overline B$, we have $S\subseteq \overline S\subseteq\bigcup_{j=1}^m U_j$ and $\overline{\bigcup_{j=1}^m U_j}=\bigcup_{j=1}^m \overline U_j$ compact.

$[(2)\Rightarrow (3)]$ Obvious.

$[(3)\Rightarrow (1)]$ Let $x\in X$. Since $X$ is T1, $\{x\}$ is closed and therefore Borel. $\{x\}$ is also compact, therefore by (3) the point $x$ has a comapct neighbourhood. For Hausdorff spaces, this is one of the equivalent characterizations of being locally compact.

Comment: Thanks! So I guess the general summary is that local compactness is necessary!